# How to decode binary to ASCII?

Tags: python-3.x, binary

I'm a python programmer and I have a problem I can transform my input in to binary :

```
bnr = open("binary.bin", "w")
tobinary = input("Enter whatever you want : ")
limit = 100
d = tobinary.encode()
if limit >= len(tobinary):
    for i in d:
        bnr.write(bin(i)[2:])
    bnr.close()
bi = open("binary.bin", "r")
read = bi.read()
bi.close()
print(read)
```

But I can't do inverse please help.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, with the approach you are doing you will not be able to do it as all the binary data gets joined up. Instead you need to put in a separator between all these binaries and use chr() and int() to recreate the data.

```
bnr = open("binary.bin", "w")
tobinary = input("Enter whatever you want : ")
limit = 100
d = tobinary.encode()
if limit >= len(tobinary):
    for i in d:
        bnr.write(bin(i)[2:]+' ')
    bnr.close()
bi = open("binary.bin", "r")
read = bi.read()
bi.close();
print(''.join([chr(int(x,2)) for x in read.split(' ')[:-1]]))
```